# Passing php json to javascript object for google map API

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps-api-3

I made a database of coordinates and other hurricane information.

```
<?php
    include '/database_connector.php'; //include database connection information
 $new = array();
 $result=mysqli_query($con, "select * from Spots15 where `Name` = 'Ana' or 'One'");
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $lat      = $row['LAT'];
  $long     = $row['LONG'];
  $latlong = $lat.", ". $long;
  array_push($new, $latlong);
}    
  echo json_encode($new);
?>
```

This is the correct output. This is the output that the api wants

```
["31.5, -77.6","31.5, -77.7","31.5, -77.5","31.6, -77.8","31.5, -77.5","31.5, -77.3","31.6, -77.3","31.7, -77.4","31.9, -77.3","32.1, -77.4","32.2, -77.5","32.4, -77.6","32.6, -77.8","32.7, -77.9","32.7, -78.1","32.9, -78.3","32.9, -78.3","33.1, -78.2","33.2, -78.3","33.6, -78.5","33.8, -78.7","34.0, -78.9","34.1, -78.9","34.1, -78.9","34.4, -78.6"]
```

I would like to pass these to the google map api can plot the coordinated on the map.

```
var four=new google.maps.LatLng(28.2,-96.0);
```

Comment: Have you done any of the Google Map API tutorials?

Comment: Yes that is how i know it is the correct way the coordinates need to go. I have the api up on my site. i have hardcoded Tropical Storm Bill into the front page. hurricanetracking.us

Comment: can you please clarify..what your question is and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: The array $new should be outputted to javascript with the following format   "var four=new google.maps.LatLng(28.2,-96.0);" I would like to make each variable a number but that might not be posslble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the data retrieve before the html tag (or also in another PHP page,  using the include function), then you can pass the PHP array to JavaScript using this row:

```
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($new) ?>;
```

At this point, inside a for loop, you can get latitude and logitude in this way:

```
var lat = Number(arr[i].split(",")[0].trim());
var lng = Number(arr[i].split(",")[1].trim());
```

After this, you can use your variables for plotting all of your points.

```
var four = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```

I hope I understood correctly your problem.

Here there is a little preview of the code.

```
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($new) ?>;
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
{
    var lat = Number(arr[i].split(",")[0].trim());
    var lat = Number(arr[i].split(",")[0].trim());
    var four = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:four,
                map:map
            });
}
```

Comment: Few questions. Do i have to have the json line in both the php code and the javascript code or can I just have it in the javascript section? Second, i can have the same variable for multiple points on a map?

Comment: You don't need the json_encode line twice in the code. Use it only in the JavaScript function.
About the other question, I didn't understood well. Could you explain what did you mean?

Comment: in your code it looks like everytime it loops it puts a different coordinate in the variable four.

Comment: Yes, it is. In this way you will plot the entire array. What's the problem?

Comment: There is not a problem in your preview what is position and map for?

Comment: You have to put the marker in your map, so you need to create a google.maps.Marker object. "position" is the point where your marker will be on the map, "map" is the map where the marker will be put.
The variable map will contain your map, and it has to be set before the first line.
Please, check the links below: they are two great tutorials on how to use the Google Maps API. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple
http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/google_maps_basic.asp

If I answered well to your questions, please vote my answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been using w3schools tutorials

Comment: That is the best tutorial. If you need some other info, more specific, check the Google tutorial. Bye!